# Lucene Query to find tokens with given distance

Tags: java, lucene

I have indexed the file content as a string in Luence (4.9), Following are some example data which were indexed in Lucene.

```
Info Object 
{ 
  String ID;
  String infoData;
}
```

`ID`   `infoData`

`1`    `Distance so far travelled 10KM`

`2`    `Distance travelled 5Miles`

`3`    `distance covered 100 Meter`

```
 doc.add(new TextField("id", info.getID(), Field.Store.YES));
 doc.add(new TextField("pdata", infoData.toString().replaceAll("(?m)^\\s", ""), Field.Store.NO));
 writer.addDocument(doc);
```

I am trying to search the following terms and expecting the output first record but I am not getting anything:

```
Term query - Distance KM
Expected output - ID = 1
```

```
 SpanNearQuery query = new SpanNearQuery(new SpanQuery[] { new SpanTermQuery(new Term("pdata", "Distance")),
            new SpanTermQuery(new Term("pdata", "KM")) }, 3, true);
    TopDocs hits = searcher.search(query, 20);
    ScoreDoc[] scoreDocs = hits.scoreDocs;
    System.out.println("Results  :" + hits.totalHits);
    for (ScoreDoc match : scoreDocs)
    {

        Document doc = searcher.doc(match.doc);
        System.out.println(doc.get("id"));

    }
```

Is there something I am missing?

Comment: Your replacement does nothing: `infoData.toString().replaceAll("(?m)^\\s", "")`. You are inserting the original String everytime.

Comment: Have you seen this one that seems relevant enough: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2021839/lucene-spannearquery-partial-matching